# EntitiyFramework4 - Save new Entity with reference to existing Entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework

My problem is quite simple. I want to save a newly created object with references to existing objects. The existing objects are loaded in another context and stored during a session. Similar to this post: [Entity Framework Attaching a Persisted Object to the New Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1903706/entity-framework-attaching-a-persisted-object-to-the-new-object)

I have this model:
[image: EntityModel]

When the user hits the new button a new sheet is created and populated with sections and fields according to the available definitions (like a template). This sheet is stored in the session and displayed. The user can enter values for the fields and save it. 
Know the problem occurs:

If I simply save the sheet the whole object graph is saved as a new object. But the definitions already are in the database -> InvalidOperationException("The EntityKey property can only be set when the current value of the property is null.")

The sheet of course cannot be attached because it has only a temporary/invalid EntityKey.

The third solution I tried: Attaching the definitions manually to the new context but Attach causes the full objectgraph to be attached which leads to a InvalidOperationException("An object with a temporary EntityKey value cannot be attached to an object context.") I checked the full graph and none of the items in the graph has a temporary EntityKey. (SectionDefinitions and FieldDefinitions). It seems that Attach() also tries to attach the Section, Field and Sheet instances.

I simply want to insert the new objects as new entries, and the existing definitions to be referenced. Do you have any ideas how to solve this problem?

The test solution is uploaded here: http://www.coderline.net/AttachingTestSuite.zip

Looking forward to your suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you finally save the sheet you should create a new object and populate it with the required ids, not references to objects that were not materialized by the current context.

This is awkward but it's expected behaviour for the ORM. Entity framework is designed based on some conventions which fit enterprise situations. It's designed to work for multi tier operations where an object tree is loaded, serialized for a different layer, de-serialized from that layer, attached to a context and saved. This means that it expects to have homogeneous objects in that tree when it's attached.

Comment: I never saw this type of usage in the EntityFramework. Is there a possibility to define referenced objects simply by IDs (using some special properties)? I would be really thankful if you have some links for me.

Comment: Thanks. I think I found the solution according to your hints. I created ForeignKeys like described here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/efdesign/archive/2009/03/16/foreign-keys-in-the-entity-framework.aspx
After that I was able to create a deep clone of my sheet which only uses IDs to refer the definitions. Thanks.

Comment: Now I have an additional problem according the update of those Sheets. This is the scenario: I load an existing Sheet from the Database and add a new section based on a definition to the Sheet. For saving the edited sheet again I need to attach the instance. And there we again encounter the problem of temporary EntitiyKeys. Do you have any idea how to manage the editing of such constructs?

Comment: Select the corresponding entries from the database, update them with the changes from the objects you have previously selected and save. You can do this with attaching, but this is easier.